# Passing URL from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am reading a rss feed with php and creating html DOM from the same. Now I have a bunch of `<li>`'s with news feed. when a user clicks on a particular `<li>` I want to post certain data to another php file which performs some other function.

How I want the data is tricky. I have a URL for all the feed elements. When a user clicks on a particular feed, I need to retrieve the URL associated with that particular feed.

I want to run a $.click() function in which I am going to $.post to the next php script.

How do I get that URL without storing it in the HTML itself. I do not want to store the URL in the html document for security puposes.

I am new with PHP.

Comment: You probably want to look into AJAX

Comment: One solution is to make an AJAX request to retrieve the URL: http://www.jorble.com/2012/01/how-to-pass-php-variables-to-javascript/

Comment: "I do not want to store the URL in the html document for security puposes."  If you're `POST`ing data, the user can see the URL using their browser's built-in tools, anyway, so "security" is a moot point.

Comment: If you don't want to store the URL in the page, you'd probably need a database to manage the URLs and store them with ids. Then you could put the ids in the page and when someone clicked the link, have a PHP script look up the corresponding URL in the database and do whatever you need with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to assign unique id (uid) to each list element that corresponds to the url. A good way of handling this would be a database. You send the list item's identifier, look up in the database the associated url, perform some magic, and send the response back to the client. You can use jQuery's `data` method that leverages the html5 data attribute to store the information. Here is the basic pseudocode.

html

```
<li class="feed" data-uid="12345">Go</li>
```

javascript

```
$('li.feed').click( function() {
    $.post({ id: $(this).data('uid') }, function(data) {
        //do something with data
    });
});
```

php

```
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
//db lookup of url
//do something with url
//return data to page
```

Answer (score 0):

you could encrypt the url being sent from the server and then decrypt when it's sent back from the client.  Just use a simple salt encryption method.  I assume you're going to use ajax or the like to post back from the client to the server in which case, this methodology would work for you.

alternatively, you could create an array and store the urls in a collection with an associative key that you send to the client, then look up the url on the server side by that key.  You could also implement a database solution to do this same thing where the key is the ID in the db.

Answer (score 0):

U have to encode the variable url...

PHP

```
var url = ...;
```

JavaScript

```
$(function (){ var d1 = <?php echo json_encode(array($url)); ?>;});
```